# Regex - Matching with the second closing tag instead of the first one

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to find the correct pattern to match the [CODE] blocks with one or more [U] inside.

Following is the sample structure contains the tags I am trying to match. Pattern should find the second [CODE] block.

```
[CODE]
    ...there is no U tag here...
[/CODE]

[U]out of the code tags[/U]

[CODE]
    ...something else...
    [U]inside the code tags[/U]
    ...something else...
[/CODE]
```

I am using the following pattern:

```
/\[CODE\](.*)\[U\](.*)\[\/U\](.*)\[\/CODE\]/gisU
```

However it is matching with the U tag out of the two CODE blocks in the middle thinking that first [CODE] and the last [/CODE] are the ones it is looking for.

How can I make this work, so it would see the first closing tag [/CODE], and   wouldn't match with the outer [U], but the one inside the second [CODE] block?

Note: I tried using ([^[/CODE]]*) to not match with the closing tag [/CODE] before the [U] in the pattern, but couldn't make it work. Obviously not very good at this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution `preg_match_all`:

```
$input = "[CODE]\n...there is no U tag here...\n[/CODE]\n\n[U]out of the code tags[/U]\n\n[CODE]\n...something else...\n[U]inside the code tags[/U]\n\n...something else...\n[/CODE]";
preg_match_all("/\[CODE\]((?!\[\/?CODE\]).)*\[U\].*?\[\/CODE\]/s", $input, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);

Array
(
    [0] => [CODE]
...something else...
[U]inside the code tags[/U]

...something else...
[/CODE]
)
```

Not much need mentioning about the PHP code itself, except that we use the `s` flag with `preg_match_all`, to make sure that we run the regex in DOT ALL mode.  This is needed because your content spans multiple lines.

Here is an explanation for the regex used:

```
\[CODE\]             match an initial [CODE] tag
((?!\[\/?CODE\]).)*  consume anything so long it is not an opening OR closing [/CODE] tag
\[U\]                consume an opening [U] tag
.*?                  then consume anything up until the first
\[\/CODE\]           closing [/CODE] tag
```

Most of the above regex is straightforward, except possibly for this part:

```
((?!\[\/?CODE\]).)*
```

This uses something called a *tempered* dot, which says to step forward one at a time, checking at each step that we do not encounter an opening `[CODE]` or closing `[/CODE]` tag.  This ensures that we match a `[U]` tag inside the set of `[CODE]...[/CODE]` tags.

Note that my answer assumes that your input is well formed, i.e. there is no nesting of tags other than what you showed us, and that every opening tag has an appropriate closing tag.  If you need to do validation on top of this, then you will have to do more work.

Comment: Tim, thank you very much. I was trying to find out "that" first part, and following pattern solved my problem by using it: \[CODE\]((?!\[\/CODE\]).)*\[U\](.*)\[\/U\](.*)\[\/CODE\] (The one you used in the sample PHP code wouldn't work if first CODE block also has U tags, but I got the point). Also thank you for the detailed description that I will read second time to make sure I got it all.